# jqGrid loses selections when request is cancelled

Tags: jqgrid

I have a requirement to allow a user to cancel a jqGrid (Version 4.4.1) paging or sorting operation if they have any selections that they do not want to lose.

I initially attempted to handle this in the `beforeRequest` event handler but when I call the `selarrrow` function an empty array is always returned as the selections appear to have already been cleared.

I then tried adding `onPaging` and `onSorting` event handlers where the selections were available via the `selarrrow` function, however, when I return 'stop' from these functions to cancel the request (as specified in the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents)) the selections still appear to have been cleared. Note the rows still appear selected in the grid but `selarrrow` returns an empty array.

I'm guessing this is a jqGrid defect but does anyone know if it has been fixed in a more recent release or if there is a configuration workaround?

Comment: The corresponding fix of jqGrid code is now merged with the main code of jqGrid on github. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are just a bug in usage of `onPaging`. If the method return `"stop"` the selection still cleared. The reason is the order of [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L2042-L2045) in the code fragment

```js
clearVals = function(onpaging){
    var ret;
    if ($.isFunction(ts.p.onPaging) ) { ret = ts.p.onPaging.call(ts,onpaging); }
    ts.p.selrow = null;
    if(ts.p.multiselect) {ts.p.selarrrow =[]; setHeadCheckBox( false );}
    ts.p.savedRow = [];
    if(ret==='stop') {return false;}
    return true;
};
```

The correct code should be

```js
clearVals = function(onpaging){
    var ret;
    if ($.isFunction(ts.p.onPaging) ) { ret = ts.p.onPaging.call(ts,onpaging); }
    if(ret==='stop') {return false;}
    ts.p.selrow = null;
    if(ts.p.multiselect) {ts.p.selarrrow =[]; setHeadCheckBox( false );}
    ts.p.savedRow = [];
    return true;
};
```

You can move the line 2045 (with `if(ret==='stop') {return false;}`) of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of the version 4.5.2 (which corresponds the line 1902 in version 4.4.1) after the 2041 (the line 1898 in version 4.4.1) (after `if ($.isFunction(ts.p.onPaging) ) { ret = ts.p.onPaging.call(ts,onpaging); }`) to fix the bug.

The usage of `onSortCol` seems be correct and if the callback returns `"stop"` string the selection should stay unchanged.

**UPDATED**: I posted the corresponding bud fix as pull request. It's merged today (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/efc0956a4be1b32d791990e1164fd758962305d7)) to the main code of jqGrid. So the next version (>4.5.2) should not have more the problem which you described.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I have put in place for this problem (note: it requires [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)) but interested in a cleaner solution if anyone has one:

```
var tempSelections,
    myGrid = $("#mygrid"),
    checkSelections = function() {
        var selections = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
        if (selections && selections.length > 0) {
            tempSelections = selections;
        }
    }; 

myGrid.jqGrid({
    ... //settings
    multiselect: true,
    onPaging: checkSelections,
    onSortCol: checkSelections,
    beforeRequest: function() {
        if (tempSelections && tempSelections.length > 0) {
            if (!confirm("Do you want to clear the selections on this page?")) {
                _.forEach(tempSelections, function(selection) {
                    myGrid.jqGrid("setSelection", selection);
                });
                tempSelections = null;
                return false;
            }
            tempSelections = null;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```